# Ubuntu / Kubuntu 18.04 + Freezing [BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS]

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, iwlwifi

I`m having a problem with some Linux distros.

My Kubuntu 18.04 LTS it`s freezing on startup SO.

I formated the computer installing Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but it`s freezing in the live-run distro, before installation.

I note the bellow error when I run:

> sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi

Stack:

```
[   21.314878] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   23.175327] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   23.175328] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[   23.175630] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   24.177863] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9462, REV=0x318
[   24.185161] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   24.185484] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[   24.230444] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 24:41:8c:bc:bb:be
[   24.333831] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   25.706306] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   25.797502] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   25.862512] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   25.870243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM =disabled)
[   25.872118] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
```

I already tried:

- update BIOS
- install another distro like Kubuntu and ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04
- update wifi firmware available in https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi, downloading Intel Wireless-AC 9462  and following the suggested steps
- Follow suggested steps in [System with Intel wireless AC-9462 freezes unless WiFi is diabled due to missing firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1040547/system-with-intel-wireless-ac-9462-freezes-unless-wifi-is-diabled-due-to-missing)

But nothing works.

Config:

- Dell Vostro 3480
- BIOS: Version 1.11.0
- SO: Trying Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

We see this clue in your dmesg:

> Conflict between TLV & NVM regarding enabling LAR (TLV = enabled NVM
> =disabled)

I suggested that you try a driver parameter:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi lar_disable=Y
```

If it seems to have solved the hang issue then I suggest that you make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi lar_disable=Y"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

You should be all set.